# エンドツーエンドの暗号化ではメディアコンテンツの暗号化は難しいのですか？

Tags: security, encryption

ツイッターを見ていると、このようなツイートを見かけました

> E2EE は原理上鍵交換が信頼できる形で行われてるか利用者から検証することがかなり難しい、データ量の都合でメディアコンテンツは暗号化されない(できない)ことが多い、概念が難しすぎて一般客からはそうしたあれこれの妥当性を理解できない、などベネフィットとダルさがあまり釣り合ってないと思う

https://twitter.com/ssig33/status/1520601791942987776

言及されている2つの特性（？）について、本当なのか疑問に思ったので調べていました

- E2EE は原理上鍵交換が信頼できる形で行われてるか利用者から検証することがかなり難しい
- データ量の都合でメディアコンテンツは暗号化されない(できない)ことが多い

「E2EE は原理上鍵交換が信頼できる形で行われてるか利用者から検証することがかなり難しい」というのは、エンドツーエンドの暗号化を実装したとうたうアプリケーションで、エンドツーエンドの暗号化が正しく行われているかを検証するには暗号に関するものに限らず広く技術的な知識を要し、検証が困難という意味だと推測しました。

しかし「データ量の都合でメディアコンテンツは暗号化されない(できない)ことが多い」については全く理由が思いつきませんでした。私の理解ではTLSのように公開鍵暗号で共通鍵を共有し、その共通鍵を使い暗号化することでメディアコンテンツの暗号化してのやり取りも行え、その上暗号化の速度の面でも共通鍵暗号方式なら問題にならないのでは、と思っています。

そこで2つ質問があります。

- ツイートで言及されている2つの特性に対する私の理解は間違いありませんか？
- エンドツーエンドの暗号化で「データ量の都合でメディアコンテンツは暗号化されない(できない)ことが多い」のはなぜなのでしょうか？

Comment: 文脈としては[こちらのツイート](https://twitter.com/ssig33/status/1520603028906123264)につながるようで、少なくとも対サーバー通信における途中経路についての話ではなさそうです。（むしろそれは今や当たり前ともいえる）（E2EE文脈ですしね）まあ、ツイートの文字数ではかなり端折られていて気になる内容にはなっているようですが……

Answer (score 2):

大前提となる「エンドツーエンド」を正しく理解されているか、気になりました。

例えば、私がスマホで撮影した写真（メディアコンテンツ）をTwitterにアップロードし、それを1000人のフォロワーさんが閲覧したとします。「エンドツーエンド」とはどこからどこへの通信かわかりますか？

- × Twitterサーバーから各フォロワーの閲覧環境まで
- 〇 私のスマホから（Twitterサーバーを経由し）各フォロワーの閲覧環境まで

となります。1000人の閲覧者がいるならば、スマホは1000回メディアコンテンツを送信する必要が生じます。というのも単一の鍵で暗号化した場合には他人が復号可能ということを意味するため、閲覧者ひとりひとりに対して異なる鍵で暗号化し、送信する必要が生じるためです。

そのような構成は非現実的なため、一般的には「エンドツーエンド」暗号化を諦めています。TwitterであればTwitterサーバー側で一旦復号し、Twitterサーバーから各フォロワーの閲覧環境への送信の際に改めて暗号化が行われています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。無数の閲覧者がいるときは送信者と受信者の鍵交換が困難（鍵を生成・交換するために送信者は常にデバイスを待機状態にしていなければならないなどの理由？）ということだと理解しました。そのうえでさらにお聞きしたいことがあります。

Comment: hinaloeさんがコメントで教えてくださったツイートを読みますと、質問で引用したツイートはE2EEの採用されたアプリケーションとしてLINEやSignalなどのある程度人物の限られたグループチャットを前提としている節があります。なのでさらにお聞きしたいのですが、グループチャットのような人数が少数である（Twitterのように無制限の閲覧者がいるわけではない）ケースでもご回答いただいたような問題が生じますでしょうか？